# batch generate thumbnails

Tags: ffmpeg, thumbnails

I am looking for a way to batch generate thumbnails contact-sheets with ffmpeg.
A single line bash command line will do but a script is also okay.

This a example.
[image]

-The dimensions of the jpg must be 1498x753 pixels
-4 rows and 4 columns
-the first thumbnail 55 seconds into the video
-the rest of the thumbnails evenly spread till the end of the video and it must have the time in the nail itself when it was made
-it must include information about movie size, duration, resolution, length and name
-it must make thumbnails for all video's in the directory
-if there is a error it must stop and print the name of the faulty video

I’m using a debian based distro.
I looked at the ffmpeg man page but it is way above my level of understanding. I also searched the web and fount nothing.
I hope some one knows.